# Disabling and enabling back button

Tags: android

In the app i m looking for the users location using gps.In the Async pre execute method i m showing a toast.I want that while i show that toast the back button should be disabled

aftr the location is found i want to enable the back button in the post execute!

to disable the back button i have used.But this is not working

```
 OnKeyListener mainScreenKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    boolean disableEvent = false;
                    if (event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        disableEvent = true;
                    }

                    return disableEvent;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Not sure of what you are willing to do. What do you mean exactly by enabling/disabling the back button? Please describe the expected behaviour of the app.

Comment: Is your 'onkey' function executed? See what happens if you use onBackPressed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare global variable `disableEvent` by

```
final boolean disableEvent;
```

Your `Preexecute` method can set it to `false` by

```
disableEvent = false;
```

Your `Postexecute` method can set it to `true` by

```
disableEvent = true;
```

You can override onBackPressed as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (disableEvent)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method is thrwoing errors...syntax error on "void", @expected

Comment: Don't copy it as it is. Just override onBackPressed Method and copy the contents of the method.

Comment: It is not working is it becoz that my class already has a onbackpressedmethod. so when i call the on backpressed method inside my inner class its not taking that?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

Assign one static variable.and set its value to "NO" in onPreExecute.
in onPostExecute assign its value to "YES".

And write following code in your onBackPressed.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

       if (decision.equals("NO")) {  //Here no means dont allow user to go back

       } else {
           super.onBackPressed(); // Process Back key  default behavior. 
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

hi for disable you simply call the above function

```
public void onBackPressed()
        {
         }
```

for enable

```
 public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        super.finish(); 
        //Intent
    }
 if you want both set flag inside the function
```

Comment: Since i m using a an inner class so how do i make sure that onback pressed of the inner class is called

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPress method in your activity

```
Class A
{
    public static boolean isToastShown=false;



    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
               if(isToastShown==true)
                 return false;
               else
                 super.onBackPressed();

             }

}

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
           //Show your toast here
           A.isToastShown=true;


new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                A.isToastShown=false;

            }
        }.start();


      }
```