# Disable back button, while in camera intent (from media store) in java(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I need to completely disable the back button when taking a picture because my setup creates a file before the camera activity starts, therefore the user must go ahead with the picture. 
Adding `finish();` right after `startActivity();` takes me out (after removing all the activity stacks) so I removed it.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}// end of disable back event
```

Using the above code, doesn't affect the camera activity so only works in the activity that calls the camera intent
Is there a way to have the above method attached to the  `startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);` activity?

Thanks!

Comment: try this hope this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13454071/3790150

Comment: thanks, still not getting called though

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for anyone else that needs to disable back button in camera mode and force the user to take the photo and save it.

(I needed to do just that because i had already created a file before the camera activity began and named it accordingly, however my case was all temporary so i just added the following)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //setups
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){}
        else {

//THE REST OF WHATEVER YOU DO WITH THE PICTURE HERE

}  
}
```